# can't change vscode python interpreter to leave virtual environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.7, interpreter, virtual-environment

I don't seem to know how to make python 3.7 as my default virtual environment on vscode, Everytime I change my interpreter so that I am not working in a virtual environment, a folder called '.vscode' appears with a '.json' file within it that has the following code within it:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe"
}
```

when i delete this folder, the interpreter changes back to a virtual environment. I want to work with pandas and other libraries but some of them don't become recognized in a virtual environment which is for some reason part of my default setup.

here's an image of how it looks like:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdpGU.png)

plus the side bar which might or might not be of some help (I'm relatively unfamiliar to coding and technology in general hahaha).

[link to screen shot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfYTN.png)

[Here's my interpreters, I would like to make python 3.7.7 64-bit my default interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98fF.png)

In Summary:
how to i make python 3.7 my default interpreter without a virtual environment and how do i stop the 'vscode' folder from loading everytime i try to quit the default virtual environment. I also can't seem to leave my virtual environment leading me to be unable to use libraries such as pandas.

I didn't have this problem for a few days but then something must have happened which automatically caused these problems.

Comment: In my experience, VSCode does not specify a default Python interpreter, which is usually specified by the user. You don't have to be so resistant to folder `.vscode`, it is part of VSCode to help us make the necessary settings. Just leave it there.

Comment: but I still can't seem to access other interpreters. Everytime i try to switch interpreter it just returns back one of my virtual environments.